# Probability of an area of pizza covered by multiple toppings.

Tags: probability, permutations, induction, combinations

"Toppings are put on circular pizzas in a random way. Every topping is placed on a randomly chose semi-circular half of the pizza (each topping chosen independently). For each topping, the pizza maker starts by drawing a diameter whose angle with the horizontal is selected uniformly at random. This divides the pizza into to semi circles. One of the two halves are chosen at random to be covered by the topping."

1. for a $2$ topping pizza what is the probability that at least $\frac 1 4$ of the pizza is covered by both toppings.
2. 

For a $3$ topping pizza, what is the probability that some region (non zero area) has all three toppings. (DIAGRAM DEPICTION PROVIDED) [image: image for 3 topping pizza]

3. For an $n$ topping pizza what is the probability that some non zero area has all $n$ toppings $(n ≥ 1)$

My answers: ($T$ represents topping)

1)
Probability of $T_1$ on one half is $\frac 1 2$.

Probably of $T_2$ on other half is $\frac 1 2$

$\text {P(both on the same half)} = \frac 1 4$.

$P(\text{at least }\frac 1 4^{\text {th}}\text{ having both topping)} = 2 \cdot \frac 1 4,\, = \frac 1 2$

2. I repeated the same thing for $2$ and got $\frac 1 {2^3} = \frac 1 8$
3. I am assuming the answer to be $\frac 1{2^n}$. (Can prove using induction)

Are my methods and answers correct?

Comment: What are the steps for proving by induction? 

1. Prove for case $n=0$ the statement is true. 
2. Prove that if for case $n$ the statement is true, then the statement is also true for case $n+1$

Comment: @M.Reeves shouldn't it be n=1 and not 0 since it is mentioned in the question that n≥1. Also, is the logic/method that I have used correct?

Comment: It's the same thing, the numbering is arbitrary as long as all of your interest cases are covered. Your proof is missing the generalization component where you examine a general $n$ many toppings.

Comment: have a look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4420571/complicated-pizza-probability-question